# Error Vectores Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo que comprobar una tabla de multiplicar y me da error cuando quiero enviar los resultados a la vista:

En la vista :

```
<form action="FormTablaJuego" method="POST">
            {!! csrf_field(); !!}
            @for($i=0;$i<11;$i++) 
             {!! \Session::get('num') !!} * {!! $i !!} = <input type='text' name='caja[]' value=''><br/>
            @endfor
            <input type='submit' value='Comprobar' name="btncomprobar"><br/>
            <input type='submit' value='Rendirse' name="btnrendirse"><br/>
        </form>
```

En esa vista recojo los numeritos que va poniendo el usuario.

```
/-------------------------------
```

En el controlador :

```
public function comprobar($array) { //es llamada desde el jugar
for ($i = 0 ;$i < count($array); $i++){ 
            if($i* \Session::get('num') == $array[$i]){
                $colores[$i]='green';
            }else{
                $colores[$i]='red';
                $perder = 1;
            }

        }


        $datos=['usuario'=>$array,
                'comprobacion'=>$colores];
       return $datos;
}


public function jugar(Request $request) {

        $comprobar = $request->get('btncomprobar');
        $rendirse = $request->get('btnrendirse');

        $usuario = $request->get('caja');

        if ($comprobar == null) { //pulsó rendirse

        } else { 
            $datos = $this->comprobar($usuario);
            return view('Jugar', $datos );

        }

    }
```

Y Finalmente la vista donde voy a mostrar los datos :

```
 <form action="FormTablaJuego" method="POST">
            {!! csrf_field(); !!}
            <?php for($i=0;$i<11;$i++){ ?> 
            {!! \Session::get('num') !!} * {!! $i !!} = <input type='text' name='caja[]' value='<?php echo usuario[$i]; ?>' style="background-color:<?php echo comprobacion[$i]; ?> " ><br/>
            <?php } ?>
            <input type='submit' value='Comprobar' name="btncomprobar"><br/>
            <input type='submit' value='Rendirse' name="btnrendirse"><br/>
        </form>
```

El error Pág 1:

```
ErrorException in 1e32fa23441faa78df6cb6471d014a37 line 46:

Use of undefined constant usuario - assumed 'usuario'
    1. in 1e32fa23441faa78df6cb6471d014a37 line 46
    2.at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Use of undefined constant usuario - assumed 'usuario'', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ComprobarTabla\storage\framework\views\1e32fa23441faa78df6cb6471d014a37', '46', array('__path' => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ComprobarTabla\storage\framework\views/1e32fa23441faa78df6cb6471d014a37', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'usuario' => array('0', '4', '8', '12', '16', '20', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), 'comprobacion' => array('green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red')), 'obLevel' => '1', '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'usuario' => array('0', '4', '8', '12', '16', '20', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), 'comprobacion' => array('green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red'), 'i' => '0')) in 1e32fa23441faa78df6cb6471d014a37 line 46
    3.at include('C:\xampp\htdocs\ComprobarTabla\storage\framework\views\1e32fa23441faa78df6cb6471d014a37') in PhpEngine.php line 42
    4.at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\xampp\htdocs\ComprobarTabla\storage\framework\views/1e32fa23441faa78df6cb6471d014a37', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'usuario' => array('0', '4', '8', '12', '16', '20', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), 'comprobacion' => array('green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red'))) in CompilerEngine.php line 58
    5.at CompilerEngine->get('C:\xampp\htdocs\ComprobarTabla\resources\views/Jugar.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'usuario' => array('0', '4', '8', '12', '16', '20', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), 'comprobacion' => array('green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red'))) in View.php line 147
    6.at View->getContents() in View.php line 118
```

El error Pág 2 :

```
ErrorException in 1e32fa23441faa78df6cb6471d014a37 line 46:

Use of undefined constant usuario - assumed 'usuario' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ComprobarTabla\resources\views\Jugar.blade.php)

1. in 1e32fa23441faa78df6cb6471d014a37 line 46
2.at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
3.at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\xampp\htdocs\ComprobarTabla\storage\framework\views/1e32fa23441faa78df6cb6471d014a37', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'usuario' => array('0', '4', '8', '12', '16', '20', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), 'comprobacion' => array('green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red'))) in CompilerEngine.php line 58
4.at CompilerEngine->get('C:\xampp\htdocs\ComprobarTabla\resources\views/Jugar.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'usuario' => array('0', '4', '8', '12', '16', '20', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), 'comprobacion' => array('green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red'))) in View.php line 147
5.at View->getContents() in View.php line 118
6.at View->renderContents() in View.php line 83
```

La Tabla usada fue la del  " 4 " Y se puede ver como coge bien los datos ('0', '4', '8', '12', '16', '20', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), Estos datos están en la variable usuario que es de la que se está quejando ...

También coge bien los valores de "green o red " si es correcto o incorrecto.

Por lo tanto no entiendo porque está dando el error.

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('Jugar', $datos );


value='<?php echo usuario[$i]; ?>'
```

Esa ultima linea esta mal, tu solo mandas datos, lo correcto seria:

```
return view('Jugar')->with('datos', $datos);
```

y en la vista

```
 value='{{ $datos['usuario'] }}'
```